# Scheduler in mysql

Tags: mysql

Is there any option in MySQL to run a scheduler job? At end of the day take some records from table1 (last 3 weeks days via sql query) and transfer to another db's table.

Please give some heads up on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there's the [event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) (since MySQL 5.1.6)

```
CREATE EVENT myevent
    ON  SCHEDULE EVERY 1 DAY
    DO
      insert into mydb.mytable select something,anything from otherdb.othertable where ..... ;
```

Comment: ...huh... I didn't know about that. nice.

Answer (score 0):

<del>no, but</del> you can use a [cron job](http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference) to execute the `mysql` command :

```
mysql <my_db_name> -u<user_name> -p<password> <mysql.sql>
```